# How to send JSON file multiple images to the server in android?

Tags: android, json

```
[{"Id": 878,
"familyList": [{
        "photocopy": "\/storage\/sdcard\/jsonFiles\/captured_signs\/Signature_1582782604563.jpg",
        "signature": "\/storage\/sdcard\/jsonFiles\/captured_signs\/Signature_1582782604563.jpg"
    }]
}, 
{
  "Id": 877,
  "familyList": [{
        "photocopy": "\/storage\/sdcard\/jsonFiles\/captured_signs\/Signature_1582802338008.jpg",
        "signature": "\/storage\/sdcard\/jsonFiles\/captured_signs\/Signature_1582802338008.jpg"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: JSON is storing text data only, not Image. You have to use multipart to send image. Check this link [RetrofitImageUpload](https://github.com/pratikbutani/RetrofitImageUpload)

Comment: Hi, its not really clear what you are asking, because you have not really given us much information to go on! Can you give us a bit more detail about what you want to do here please

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Encode your image to Base64

Comment: when the image is captured, it stored in the device along with the path of the image in JSON file after the internet is available, I want to upload the JSON file to the server, with all images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store Images at a JSON file. You'll need to access the image that is currently in your Android device before you connect with the server, and parse the Image to Base64 to pass the image Bytes to the server.

Something like this...

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```